# Using Python libraries in Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10 for iOS projects

Tags: python, swift, xcode

Has anyone tried to use Python libraries in Swift with Xcode 10? Can they be used inside ios projects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do work, but it's tricky to use.